# why npm run build commad is failed?

Tags: reactjs

PS C:\Users\Chandu\react\stackoverflow\client> npm run build

> client@0.1.0 build
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

[eslint] EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\Chandu\react\stackoverflow\client\node_modules.cache.eslintcache'

Answer (score 0):

Delete your node module and run the following commands

```
npm cache verify
npm install
npm run build
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).